# Couldn't find preset "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset" relative to directory

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs

I'm trying to run my test suite but I am getting the following error:

```
Couldn't find preset "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset" relative to directory "/Users/dan/Sites/X"

      at node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:293:19
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at OptionManager.resolvePresets (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275:20)
      at OptionManager.mergePresets (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:264:10)
      at OptionManager.mergeOptions (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:249:14)
      at OptionManager.init (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
      at File.initOptions (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212:65)
      at File.initOptions (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/util/hacks.js:23:43)
      at new File (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135:24)
      at Pipeline.transform (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)
```

Here's my `jest` config in `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js",
      "\\.(ts|ts)x?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "/src/.*.spec.(js|ts|tsx)?$",
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "useBabelrc": true
      }
    }
  }
```

If needed, here's the contents of `babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "alias": {
          "~": "./src"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Discussion here: https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/242

Answer (score 6):

[This issue](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/242) remains open at the time of writing.

Users seem to have mixed results with the fixes, but these two worked for me:

### Option 1: Change .babelrc to .babelrc.js

Simply rename `.babelrc` to `.babelrc.js` or `babel.config.js`.

Don't forget to add `module.exports =`  to the beginning of the file.

This fixed my jest issue but broke other eslint plugins for me.

### Option 2: Add transform to Jest config

For option 2, I think it works around the issue by manually invoking the react-native preprocessor on all javascript files.

```
transform: { '^.+\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js' }
```

If you don't have a separate Jest config file, you can add it to your package.json like...

```
{
  "jest": {
    "transform": { 
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js" 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that `transform` in the JSON example needs to be wrapped in double quotes (`"transform"`).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same warning in console. I fixed it by running this command:

```
npm i metro-react-native-babel-preset --save-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

just deleting the node_modules and the yarn.lock or node.lock and running yarn again took care of that problem for me